# How to use hadoop-pcap library to extract packet payload data, specifically hexdump of any packet?

Tags: java, hadoop, pcap, hadoop2, jnetpcap

I am using a hadoop-pcap library from here:
[hadoop-pcap-lib](https://github.com/RIPE-NCC/hadoop-pcap/tree/master/hadoop-pcap-lib)
But i am unable to extract packet payload data. I need hexdump of each packet. In Jnetpcap i am able to do that by using `packet.toHexdump(packet.size(), false, true, false);`.

I want to use similar function in this library. There is a function defined in `net.ripe.hadoop.pcap.PcapReader.java` called `readPayload()`, but it takes parameters